# Getting white corners when using border radius

Tags: html, css

I am creating a little box with a header but the problem is that the background is coming through and showing on the corners. Not sure why this is happening since I have set `border-radius` for both the box and the header the same. I would prefer to keep the header inside of the box.

**Screenshot:**

[image: white corners]

**Here is my code:**

```css
body {
    background: #292929;
}

.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.box-header {
    background: #353535;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: inherit;
    border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probs rounding issue, the inner box is 1px smaller, and the white is showing underneath.

Comment: @0stone0 how do you fix it?

Comment: There are tons of questions about this but none of them has a clear solution since it's based on your DOM. Consider adding margin, or even better, just make it 2 elements.

Comment: Wanted to post a answer, but question has already been flagged. personally i thought this is not a duplicate because we aren't talking about 2 overlapping elements. But the public has spoken.